# Why do I have to 'vote to delete' my own answer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, self-delete

Actually, I don't, but the message leads to confusion:

Wait... I have to wait for more votes to have this embarrassing and compromising answer deleted?

Comment: ROLLBACK WARRRRRRRR!

Comment: Don't fan the flames, evil mmyers. I'm just trying to get Jeff to explain himself because his is a non answer (to at least 10 people and probably some more.)

Comment: Aceptar. Just click Aceptar.

Comment: This is still not fixed?

Answer (score 10):

Nope, it is just deleted. You have to 'vote' to close your own questions though.

But, you can always undelete the answer. And it is viewable to people with 10K+ rep I believe.

Comment: Yes. The bug is the message in the popup when deleting your own answers. And yes, 10k+ people can see and even edit them.

Comment: 10k+ people can see your dirty underwear, even if you threw it out

Answer (score 7):

Gone the client side only route on this one.

Starting with the next build, self-deletes will prompt "Delete this post?".

Answer (score -13):

see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/adventures-in-delclusionism/

edit: updating the client-side javascript to negotiate with the server and figure out this distinction is far more code work than this justifies.

Comment: Do you actually ever read questions in full? In that blog post you say: "First: who can delete things? Post authors can delete their own questions or answers." And that is true, only the popup message text is wrong and misleading.

Comment: Can you state why the popup saying 'vote to delete this post?', **when you are the answer writer and you are deleting your own answer**, is by design? That blog post only says answer owners *can delete* their answers. Again, I'm talking about *answers* here. BTW, I understand and agree with your point about questions.

Comment: Vinko, from the podcasts we know he does not listen, from his answers we know he does not read.

Comment: I got a lot on my mind-grapes.

Comment: Jeff, don't whine ;)

Comment: Can't you have different javascript snippets sent from the server, one for answers and one for questions? After all when you display an answer you already know it is an answer, and there's no delete link on answers for non-owners. There's no need to negotiate anything

Comment: For anybody else who's having as much trouble following the thread of this discussion as I did, it appears that @John the Seagull's user name used to be Vinko.

Comment: @Jeff: Any chance you might reconsider this decision now? It's [still confusing users](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/752).

Comment: yea i was confused and spent 3 days trying to figure this out.

Comment: @jostster On your original question you said "I clicked delete and the alt said vote to delete and I still saw my answer (since I was the OP, at the time i didn't know it still shows for the op) was there, I was confused". Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't it really obvious when a post is deleted? Besides the tinted background (which admittedly you wouldn't know if you're new), it says "deleted X hours ago" in bold red text right under the link bar

Comment: @Michael Yes it took about 10 minutes for the background to change.  I guess that maybe a cron script runs which marks them as deleted?

Comment: @jostster No, it should change immediately (you might need to refresh for answers, I haven't deleted one recently and don't remember)

Comment: @Michael It is displayed after a refresh. The only immediate change is the "delete" link changes to say "undelete". But it even retains the tooltip for the original "delete" link, and the post does not have the "deleted by X" message that it will get after refresh. It is, in fact, very much not obvious that your answer is immediately deleted.

Comment: "negotiate with the server"?  C'mon, the names of the author and the user are both visible on the client, and could easily be made accessible to client-side code if they aren't already.  BTW... I didn't know till I read this who the deleted post was visible to and when.