# When deleting your own answer the confirmation dialog should read "delete your answer?"

Tags: feature-request

When you press delete on your own answer a confirmation dialog pops up, asking "Vote to delete this post?". I find that confusing, because you are not voting, you are really deleting it. It should read "Delete this post?" instead.

Comment: This can be marked [meta-tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been declined for no good reason. See

[Why do I have to 'vote to delete' my own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Jeff indicates in the post linked by Vinko that fixing this would be far more effort than it's worth.  I don't know how things are with other dev teams, but that's their judgment call and to me it is sufficient reason to decline to fix the bug.

The best you could ask for is `status-deferred`, implying that it will get fixed when other higher-priority things are addressed.  However, IMHO, `status-declined` is more honest, because the chances of this actually getting fixed are really small.

Comment: Of course it is their call to make, but that doesn't mean you have to agree with the stated reasons. Besides, if you look at the history of the question, there is place for a reasonable doubt that the problem was even really understood.

Comment: @Vinko:  It's true that you don't have to agree, but I think that you cannot disagree either.  Since we can't see the code, we can't judge whether it's as difficult as they say.  Therefore, you can either trust their judgment and agree, you can simply say "I don't have enough information to agree or disagree", or you can outright disagree, which is essentially saying their assessment is a lie.

Comment: @Vinko:  Actually, my bad, there's nothing stopping you from believing their assessment is a lie and disagreeing on that grounds.  It's just not the choice I would make.  But if you want to do that, more power to you.

Comment: @Adam: Their assessment is not boolean. They could have misunderstood the problem, in which case the assessment is just incorrect. But in this particular case I just plainly disagree without having seen the code and even assuming the assessment is correct. I just cannot imagine a need to negotiate this popup with the server and thus I think it's a mistake. I admit I may be wrong and that there might be a very good reason for that negotiation. But I've chosen to disagree on the belief that it's either a misunderstanding or a mistake. You can take decisions without complete information.

Comment: @Adam: Summing up. I can choose to believe that they are making a mistake and disagree on that grounds, even without having complete information and without calling anybody a liar.

Comment: @Vinko: That's true.  I forgot Hanlon's Razor: Never ascribe to malice that which can be explained by incompetence.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.