# Deleted shading doesn't appear without a refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, deleted-answers, information-display

I noticed that when deleting an answer, the shading doesn't appear until you hit refresh.  The only indication it's deleted is the 'delete' text changing to the red 'undelete' which is subtle enough that I've wondered a couple times if I'd hit the 'delete' button (which is when I then look and see the 'undelete' text).  Seems like it would be a pretty minor fix to have the shading implement immediately.

(This was using Firefox 3.5.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This now happens instantly, fixed some time ago in the way delete work and when classes/styles are applied.

Answer (score 1):

When this problem is combined with the ["vote to delete this post"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer) message on your own answers, I was very confused. It's not clear that you can actually delete your own answer. After you click OK, it's not clear that you have done so. I think that fixing either of these problems would clarify things.