# Deleted inline answer update doesn't apply background style after update

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, live-refresh

When on a question, if a user decides to make edits and delete their post (and you click the gray 'update' bar) the post is flagged with the deleted text but the red background is absent (until you refresh the page, then it renders properly).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possibly (but not exactly) related: [Deleted shading doesn't appear without a refresh](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35696/deleted-shading-doesnt-appear-without-a-refresh)

Comment: No dice still? Sad panda.