# Post background not updated when deleted post is loaded

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, live-refresh

> Related: [Deleted inline answer update doesn't apply background style after update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163411/deleted-inline-answer-update-doesnt-apply-background-style-after-update), [Deleted shading doesn't appear without a refresh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35696/deleted-shading-doesnt-appear-without-a-refresh)

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149054/178687) suggests that the red "deleted" background should appear immediately after the post is deleted. However, for me, I still have to refresh the page to get the red background. Otherwise, I get the red "undelete" text with an ordinary white background, as appears here: [Deleted inline answer update doesn't apply background style after update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163411/deleted-inline-answer-update-doesnt-apply-background-style-after-update)

Note that in my case, it was when an entire question was deleted along with its answers; neither the question nor answers were coloured after the deletion (only coloured when I refreshed).