# Alt tag for 'delete'

Tags: bug, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I have to 'vote to delete' my own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer)

The alt tag for the delete option says "vote to delete" however if you are the OP of the answer you aren't actually "voting" to delete you are deleting the answer.  Shouldn't the tag say if you are an OP "mark as deleted" and if you are not the OP it should say "vote to delete"?

Comment: Declined over at [Why do I have to 'vote to delete' my own answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer). The work for implementation was determined to outweigh the benefits.

Comment: I beg to differ.  I spent 3 days searching how to delete my own answer because when I clicked delete and the alt said vote to delete and I still saw my answer (since I was the OP, at the time i didn't know it still shows for the op) was there, I was confused.  I thought people had to still have other users vote to delete their answer.

Comment: You beg to differ that the work outweighs the benefits, or beg to differ that it is a duplicate?

Comment: the first, that the work outweighs the benefits.

Comment: Well, I won't argue with you on that. I'm neutral, probably because I'm adjusted to the concept that people can have finalizing votes (like how diamonds can close definitively), but I can understand that not everyone will understand that distinction. Upvote the duplicate I linked to indicate your support for getting this changed, that would be a prudent course of action.

Comment: And judging from your newness, I'll also teach you a tip about this site, if you aren't aware of it. Inside a comment, if you prepend an at-sign to someone's name, like say @GraceNote, that user will be notified of the comment you just typed. There are some important rules regarding it to ensure your message gets to its destination, which you can read up on [over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020). ♪

Comment: @GraceNote: thank you I wasn't aware of that.  I tried to upvote but didn't have enough rep to do an upvote.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, @jostster! You might also want to check out [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work) when you have a moment; it could save you some heartburn down the road.

Comment: @GraceNote:  I received a reply message in my notifications when you did not use my @name.  Was that just because you replied to my question?

Comment: That is correct. When you comment on a post, then that post's author will get a notification even without the syntax.

Comment: @Grace:  would you mind making your first commend an answer so I can mark this as answered?