# Unable to delete own answers -- the delete link is gone!

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete

[I'm not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815106/php-date-format-question/5815164#5815164) seeing, or rather, not seeing the delete links any longer for our own answers:

[image: Two, two, two memes in one!]

It seems that age of the question and age of the answer have no impact on the missing link.

Just to make sure, it also doesn't seem to have moved to the edit page.

(Expected links should [look like those in this previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-i-have-to-vote-to-delete-my-own-answer).)

Comment: fixing this ... hold tight

Comment: Praise waffles!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Our code is heavily reliant on the Linq-2-SQL identity map. This happened cause we had a comparison in the line of `this == p.Owner`, the safe way of doing such a compare is `this.Id == p.OwnerId` not only is it safer, it is faster.

Today I ported the bulk of question/show to dapper, which brought out a few glitches, on the upside, question show is now 10-15% faster and questions with TONS of answers are much faster (like x2)