# Can' t delete own answers in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

It looks as if the browser-based fix mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89083/unable-to-delete-own-answers-the-delete-link-is-gone) to users being unable to delete their own answers wasn't applied to the Android app. In the app, the delete link is never there.

Comment: You currently can't delete posts, at all, from the apps.