# Wrong mouse-over message for self-delete link

Tags: bug, tooltips, wording, self-delete

The mouse-over text for the *delete* or *undelete* link on a user's own question or answer confusingly states *“Vote to (un)delete this post”*. Clicking the link performs the expected action (message asking only "Delete this post?") but the tooltip is misleading, since the vote is binding.

Apparently, this was [fixed in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173434/229493) (set to `status-completed`) so I presume some sort of regression crept back in.

Comment: From the answer, it looks like that's all the fix they intended to do at the time, but I'd agree that the tooltip should still be changed.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'd actually read that statement as an implicit intent to fix the tooltip text since that's what the original bug report referred to but you're probably right that they forgot about the mouse-over text since it wasn't stated explicitly.

Comment: In my experience, a number of bug reports are marked complete when they implement something more or less similar to the original request. (Occasionally, even when the implementation isn't very similar at all.)